# password_hash equivalent for php 5.4?

Tags: php, hash, passwords, salt

I developed my site using XAMPP with php 5.5 installed. I just realize that my host only has php 5.4 (cannot update to 5.5 yet). My problem is that I cannot use the new php 5.5 `password_hash()` feature. Is there an equivalent method for hashing with salt for php 5.4?

Is there a way to get this equivalent code (below) to work in php 5.4?

```
$options = [
  'salt' => uniqid(mt_rand(), true),
  'cost' => 12 
];
$hash = password_hash($mypassword, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, $options);
```

Comment: Why are you using `mt_rand` to generate a salt? `password_hash` generates a much more secure salt by default.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use [password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). It's a backward compatible library to emulate [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) in older versions of PHP (5.3.7+).

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. Is the simple hash/salt that I posted safe to use? I know there are better ways, but this is what was in the php manual..

Comment: No, the generation of the salt is not secure enough in your code. Let the library generate the salt.

Comment: I kinda like Whirlpool myself ;)

Comment: @bagofmilk when you say "*You know there are better ways*", what specifically are you talking about?

Comment: @bagofmilk Where is using `mt_rand` to generate a salt in the PHP manual? It is not in the examples for `password_hash`

Answer (score 5):

When I was using PHP 5.4 I used php's [crypt function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) with CRYPT_BLOWFISH hash type. I played a bit with parameters to match your case, and concluded that your `blowfish Pre` should be `$2y$12$` to match your `cost = 12` parameter.

You can run this script in your command line to verify the result matches (**I will keep your insecure mt_rand salt in this part. More on this later**)

```
<?php

$salt= uniqid(mt_rand(), true);
$options=['salt'=>$salt, 'cost'=>12];
$mypassword=$argv[1];

$cryptpwd=crypt($mypassword,'$2y$12$'.$salt.'$'); // PHP 5.4 style

$pwdhash=password_hash($mypassword, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, $options);  // PHP 5.5+

echo "\n";
echo 'CRYPT    :'. $cryptpwd;
echo "\n";
echo 'PWD HASH :'. $pwdhash;
echo "\n";

if($cryptpwd===$pwdhash) {
    echo 'Hashes match!';
} else {
    echo 'Hashes do not match';
}
echo "\n";
```

For example

```
php pwd.php 1q2w3e4r5t
```

outputs

```
CRYPT    :$2y$12$22253563353f27f9b3292ereZv98r1iFQhItfYT0UbKaejMSJThBi
PWD HASH :$2y$12$22253563353f27f9b3292ereZv98r1iFQhItfYT0UbKaejMSJThBi
Hashes match!
```

@JohnConde's answer is better because is safer using a well tested library. I just wanted to see what was going below the trunk.

PD: You asked

> Is there a way to get this equivalent code (below) to work in php 5.4?

Now, your code has a **major weakness**. You are generating salts with mt_rand. **Don't ever do that**. Trust the system with the salt generation and, if you really want to generate it yourself, use something like the following salt generator (I used thisone when my apps were PHP 5.4)

```
$Allowed_Chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789./';
$Chars_Len = 63;
$Salt_Length = 21;
$salt = "";
$Blowfish_Pre='$2y$12$';
$Blowfish_End='$';

for ($i = 0; $i < $Salt_Length; $i++) {
    $salt.= $Allowed_Chars[mt_rand(0, $Chars_Len) ];
}

$bcrypt_salt = $Blowfish_Pre . $salt . $Blowfish_End;
```

To be honest I was sure the salt had 18 characters, but looking at my old code, it's done with 21 :)

Comment: Please, pretty please, don't advocate using `mt_rand()` for anything related to security.

Comment: Yeah well, I guess you didn't read the bottom part of my post ;)