# Problems when converting mysql to mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to convert mysql to mysqli, but I get some errors

first error:

> mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/.........../class/class.mysql.php on line 55

```
public function query($res, $pass_no = 1) {
    $q1 = mysqli_query($res, $this->db_link);
    if (!$q1) {
        $this->sql_error();
        if ($pass_no == 1) {
            if ($this->output_error == 1) {
                echo 'Attempting to reconnect to MySQL...' . "\n";
            }
            $this->db_close();
            $this->db_connect();
            $this->query($res, 2);
        } else {
            if ($this->output_error == 1) {
                echo 'Reconnection failed; please check your MySQL server settings!' . "\n";
            }
        }
    } else {
        return $q1;
    }
}
```

second error:

> mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/..../index.php on line 14

```
global  $db ;

$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['username_login']);

      $q ="select * from ".DB_PREFIX."admins where username='".$username."' ".
        "and password='".md5( $_POST['password_login'])."'";
   // echo $q;
    $res =$db->query($q);
    if($db->num_rows($res)==1)
    {

        return true ;
    }

return false ;
```

I don't understand the 2 errors

Comment: In `mysqli_` the database Link is the ***first*** parameter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysqli\_query expects at least 2 parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073278/mysqli-query-expects-at-least-2-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

When you get errors: Please help yourself by [reading the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) .

## 1)

> first error : mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/.........../class/class.mysql.php on line 55

Your code:

```
$q1 = mysqli_query($res, $this->db_link);
```

**Should be:**

```
$q1 = mysqli_query($this->db_link, $res);
```

With the Database connection variable ***FIRST***. This variable is **required** for *almost* all `mysqli_` functions.

## 2)

> second error : mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/..../index.php on line 14

See point 1, above:

```
mysqli_real_escape_string($connectionVariable, $_POST['username_login']);
```

## 3)

```
$q ="select * from ".DB_PREFIX."admins where username='".$username."' ".
    "and password='".md5( $_POST['password_login'])."'";
```

## ***NO***

Do not do this!!! Passwords should be stored using PHPs specialist [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. Please read [how to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279321/how-to-use-password-hash), [why you should use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798275/best-way-to-store-passwords-in-mysql-database), [why it should be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054022/best-way-to-store-password-in-database?noredirect=1&lq=1), and [the benefits of using it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581610/how-can-i-store-my-users-passwords-safely) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25372636/password-hash-equivalent-for-php-5-4) if you need to use it on older versions of PHP.